# JavaScript: same element retrieved by getElementById, but .. is different?

Tags: javascript

I really hope I'm missing something obvious here. Here's a screenshot of Chrome's console, dead in front of me (well, other tab):

[image: What's the difference between one element and the other?]

`e` was retrieved via `.getElementById("overlayidentifier")` by me, from the console. The other variable is used by a rather messy script included on a site I happen to be working with.

Before I dive into the abyss of the script that originally creates and works with `overlayidentifier`, I just wanted to know.. what's going on here.

Any `.style` changes to `e` have effect - nothing happens if `overlayidentifier.style.~` is modified, though.

Where do I begin?

**Demystified. For the more curious:**

The problem was a lonely `.innerHTML +=`-esque piece of code somewhere on the page. Using `.innerHTML` causes a rebuild of the DOM structure inside the element on which it is called. So any references of elements inside, obtained prior to the `.innerHTML` assignment will get invalidated in a confusing way: they retain most of their the attributes can be interacted with normally, but they are no longer in the DOM tree. Which is evidenced by `.parentNode` returning `null`.

This was a fun waste of time, actually.

Comment: here is a screencast of some tips and tricks with the chrome console / dev tools http://talkminer.com/viewtalk.jsp?videoid=nOEw9iiopwI&q=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two elements with the id of `overlayidentifier`, as is evidenced by the little ">" arrow and the `...` that says your div has content when you type `overlayidentifier` that are not there when you type `e`

To clarify, since ***one*** of your nodes has the ">" and the other doesn't, you have two different nodes.

Comment: the ... means there are nested elements.

Comment: The disclosure triangle typically indicates that the currently-shown node has children rather than duplicates, unless a duplicate node were attached as a child of the one shown. But there's no way to tell without opening the triangle.

Comment: @Piers: cwolves is not saying that the triangle shows the presence of duplicates. But the two nodes are distinct, since one of them has child node(s) while the other has not.

Comment: @Kristian -- I know, I'm saying one has children while the other doesn't, therefore they are different nodes

Comment: @cwolves ok :) I had to reread that again to see the meaning.

Comment: Well, the answer is correct - my problem still exists, but these were indeed two elements with the same ID - one in the DOM tree, the other one not. _How_ this happened is still a mystery - there's only one element of that ID in the HTML code, and the only interaction with it is by `getElementById`, a couple `.styles` and a few `.innerHTML`s. How and when this is "cloned" is yet unknown (and frankly quite tiring). Still, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `overlayidentifier` object may be a *clone* of the DOM element with the `overlayidentifier` ID. If it were cloned, it would contain at least the same HTML and attributes (and possible the same event handlers and children, if it's a *deep clone*), but it doesn't represent the actual element inside the DOM anymore.

Making changes with `style()` won't have any visible effect until it's attached into the DOM somewhere. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

When you type straight into the chrome console, and you just write an id, it will return the element plus all of its contents. However, in your screenshot, the 'e' var returns a div with no nested elements within that div.

When I perform a getElementById() of the same ID, i get the exact same response.

What that tells me is that at the point at which your e variable was set, the contents of the div were not there, possibly.